# Sass animation mixins using includes

Tags: html, css, animation, sass

I'm trying to get a demo of this example working - but I don't see any animations taking hold. I want to compact the mixins as much as possible and use includes to try and keep the animations efficient

https://brandonbrule.github.io/scss-animation-keyframe-mixin/

my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/knum7po2/1/

```css
// CSS
.animation-slide-in-up{
  @include animation(0, 0.5s, animation-slide-in-up, ease);
}

.animation-slide-in-down{
  @include animation(0, 0.5s, animation-slide-in-down, ease);
}

.animation-slide-in-right{
  @include animation(0, 0.5s, animation-slide-in-right, ease);
}

.animation-slide-in-left{
  @include animation(0, 0.5s, animation-slide-in-left, ease);
}

.animation-slide-out-up{
  @include animation(0, 0.5s, animation-slide-out-up, ease);
}

.animation-slide-out-down{
  @include animation(0, 0.5s, animation-slide-out-down, ease);
}

.animation-slide-out-right{
  @include animation(0, 0.5s, animation-slide-out-right, ease);
}

.animation-slide-out-left{
  @include animation(0, 0.5s, animation-slide-out-left, ease);
}


@mixin keyframe ($animation_name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes $animation_name {
        @content;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes $animation_name {
        @content;
    }

    @-o-keyframes $animation_name {
        @content;
    }

    @keyframes $animation_name {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin animation ($delay, $duration, $animation, $direction: forward, $fillmode: fowards) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: $delay;
    -webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
    -webkit-animation-name: $animation;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    -webkit-animation-direction: $direction;

    -moz-animation-delay: $delay;
    -moz-animation-duration: $duration;
    -moz-animation-name: $animation;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    -moz-animation-direction: $direction;

    animation-delay: $delay;
    animation-duration: $duration;
    animation-name: $animation;
    animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    animation-direction: $direction;
}




// -- Slide Animations -- //

// Slide Out Top from Center
@include keyframe(animation-slide-out-up) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0,-100%);
    }
}

@include keyframe(animation-slide-out-down) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0,100%);
    }
}

// Slide Out Left from Center
@include keyframe(animation-slide-out-left) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-100%,0);
    }
}

// Slide out Right from Center
@include keyframe(animation-slide-out-right) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(100%,0);
    }
}

@include keyframe(animation-slide-in-up) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
}

@include keyframe(animation-slide-in-down) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,-100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
}

// Slide in Left to Center
@include keyframe(animation-slide-in-left) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-100%,0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
}

// Slide in Right to Center
@include keyframe(animation-slide-in-right) {
    0% {
        transform: translate(100%,0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-slide-in-up">c</div>
<div class="animation-slide-in-down">x</div>
<div class="animation-slide-in-right">x</div>
<div class="animation-slide-in-left">x</div>

<div class="animation-slide-out-up">x</div>
<div class="animation-slide-out-down">x</div>
<div class="animation-slide-out-right">x</div>
<div class="animation-slide-out-left">x</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two reasons why your sass doesn't compile:

- `@mixin` always comes first

> There is no hoisting in sass, so make sure you always put mixins and variables before you refer to them.

- If you want to use variables on selectors/property names, you need to use [interpolations(`#{}`)](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation)

Change

```
@mixin keyframe ($animation_name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes $animation_name {
        @content;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

to

```
@mixin keyframe ($animation_name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
        @content;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Here's the fixed fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hscbfeox/

Comment: I still don't see things moving?

Comment: Try to click on `Run` button @TheOldCounty

Comment: ah it moved at the start - I just thought I was watching the page init

Comment: hoisting in sass  -- tell me more -- why is it his stuff didn't include that?

Comment: Hoisting roughly means the definitions always come to the top, like [hoisting in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) you can refer to a function before you define it. But sass doesn't have that feature so you have to literally put your definition code before you refer them. Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37016833/10289265) that explains it.

Comment: I see - I am trying to apply it to this example - http://jsfiddle.net/xpb90keq/3/  trying to get the shapes to fade up - but I wanted to clean up the mixin function first

Comment: Just need to know it always is a good practice to put all your mixins and variables in a different sass/scss file and `@import` them first. Or if you're using a single sass/scss file, always put them at the top.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5f712csm/  -- I've applied it - but I can't see it working - infinite needs to be on right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5f712csm/1/  - no nothing is working - but I am sure I've copied the idea throughout

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zv2rc70d/  -- 1 item moving up - but only does so at the start -- keen to get it to fade in from the bottom fade out as it gets to the top -- and repeat infinite

Comment: Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/nsrte6g5/ . You forgot to assign `bubble` width and height. Also, you need to assign `animation-iteration-count` to `infinite` if you want the animation loops

Comment: Also, if you need to ask further about another question. You should ask another question instead. Comments are not a good place to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65192163/html5-animations-creating-fizzy-effect-on-material-ui-icon-shapes  -- question is here

Comment: bubble width and height -- where? ah the particle itself -- that's cause the width/height is dependent on the size of the icon inside it?

Comment: @TheOldCounty It is, but you forgot to assign `width` and `height` to the `svg` inside of it as well. If you inspect the element, you can see the `width` and `height` are all `0`

Comment: .magic-cloud .small .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    font-size: 15px;
}  -- there is css for it?

Comment: how do I get it so the shapes fade in at the start - and not just appear in the red zone - like start in the red and end before the red - https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-tdd-57ov7?file=/src/MagicCloud.js